# Resource for International Comparison of Math Education Logistics

Tags: undergraduate-education, secondary-education, reference-request, classroom-management

Are there resources that compares/lists crunchy facts about the logistics of math education  in different regions or countries? I'm talking facts like: Do they use paper homework versus and online homework system? And which online homework systems? Which textbooks are used, and from which publishers? How is their mathematics curriculum broken up across classes? How are students assessed? What is the ratio of homework to classwork? Etc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any detailed resources that contain (reliable and current) information in that detail and depth.
One resource might be ICMI's [Database Project](https://www.mathunion.org/icmi/activities/icmi-database-project). It is a list on math curricula and information on math education within countries.